# AttributeError: type object 'Web3' has no attribute 'eth'

Tags: web3.py, python

I am working on a smart contract integrated Django project. But When I try to check the account using `Web3.eth.accounts` get an error,

> AttributeError: type object 'Web3' has no attribute 'eth'

Other coding part given below,

```
from web3 import Web3
import time
import sys
from .auth_contract_connection import contract_address,abi
sys.path.append('../')
from connection import connection

con=Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"))
```

how I slow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call what was initialised as Web3. in your case, `con`

`con.eth.accounts`

alternatively use the standard `web3` or `w3`

`web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"))`

then your code will work with `web.eth.accounts`